# How to put double quotes in ADO.NET query?

Tags: sql, security, ado.net, sql-injection

I am trying to prevent any SQL injection in all my queries and would like to know how to put double quotes in this query. Thanks

```
string.Format("SELECT TOP 10 article_guid, article_title 
               FROM article 
               WHERE article.article_isdeleted = 0 AND 
                     FREETEXT(article_title, @val)");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Don't do this. Use a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163799.aspx#S5) instead.

Parameterized queries remove most of the risk associated with SQL injection attacks.

From the link:

```
private void CallPreparedCmd() {
    string sConnString = 
        "Server=(local);Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;";
    string sSQL = 
        "UPDATE Customers SET City=@sCity WHERE CustomerID=@sCustomerID";
    using (SqlConnection oCn = new SqlConnection(sConnString)) {
        using (SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, oCn)) {
            oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            oCmd.Parameters.Add("@sCustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5);
            oCmd.Parameters.Add("@sCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);

            oCn.Open();
            oCmd.Prepare();

            oCmd.Parameters["@sCustomerID"].Value = "ALFKI";
            oCmd.Parameters["@sCity"].Value = "Berlin2";
            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            oCmd.Parameters["@sCustomerID"].Value = "CHOPS";
            oCmd.Parameters["@sCity"].Value = "Bern2";
            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            oCn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, you can insert quotes into a string by escaping the double quotes like this:

```
string newstring = " \"I'm Quoted\" ";
```

Comment: Can parameters prevent something like this being added at the end of the query ;drop table article

Comment: Yes, because parameters are not executed as literal sql and are type checked. See http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/113/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent SQL Injection you must only use `SqlParameter` objects for all your queries, like so:

```
SqlCommand  command = new SqlCommand("update tblFoo set x = @x");
SqlParamter param   = new SqlParameter("@x", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

param.Value = "hello\"";

command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use **string.Format**? You are using @parameterized query and it is **Type-Safe**.

[Use Type-Safe SQL Parameters for Data Access](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ADO.NET_2.0_Security_Guidelines_-_SQL_Injection)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if double quotes will help you (which you can add if you like by escaping the quote, as in \").  What I've done in the past is to be mindful of single quotes, so I performed a replace on the content of @val prior to including it in the query, as in `val.Replace("'", "''").`

Comment: Sorry, downvoting because this is not the way to do it in .NET; it is not enough (i.e. imagine the parameter contains no quotes; because it is normally numeric.

Comment: Fair enough, but the OP's original post presumes that @val is textual.

Comment: I know. Hence the reason I'm sorry for it; but in .NET, there is no legitimate case to use `.Replace` to solve SQL Injection; you only ever use `SqlParameter`s.

Comment: Well, I know SqlParameters take care of this, but what about OleDbParameters and the like.  Though the OP's query gives SQL Server away, you can't always be certain of the data provider.  Not a big deal, dude.